# Cannot cast to IConvertible in Query with CustomType

Tags: c#, nhibernate

When running this code with an NHibernate session:

```
_session.Query<Order>().SingleOrDefault(o => o.EmployeeNumber == employeeNumber);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'EmployeeNumber' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

Relevant code:

```
public class Order : FOAggregateRoot
{
    private readonly int _employeeNumber;
    public virtual EmployeeNumber EmployeeNumber => (EmployeeNumber)_employeeNumber;
    private readonly IList<OrderLine> _products;
    public virtual IReadOnlyList<OrderLine> Products => _products.ToList();
    public virtual Price Total => (Price)_products.Sum(line => line.Total);

    public Order(EmployeeNumber employeeNumber) : base(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
        _products = new List<OrderLine>();
        _employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    }

    protected Order() { }
}

public sealed class EmployeeNumber : SingleValueObject<int>
{
    public EmployeeNumber(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(EmployeeNumber number)
    {
        return number.Value;
    }

    public static explicit operator EmployeeNumber(int number)
    {
        return new EmployeeNumber(number);
    }
}

public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        Id(Entity.Expressions<Order>.Id);
        Map(x => x.Uid);
        Map(x => x.EmployeeNumber)
            .Unique()
            .CustomType<int>().Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
        HasMany(x => x.Products)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All()
            .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

I kinda "understand" why this exception happens and I could solve it by either implementing `IConvertible` (which I don't want in my value object) or explicitely cast `employeeNumber` to `int`.

However I would have expected this code to run out of the box especially because I have defined an implicit cast to `int operator` in `EmployeeNumber`, which, however doesn't seem to be used by NHibernate.

Is it possible to inform NHibernate to use this `operator` in this case ?

Does any other solution exist ? (ideally, if it compiles, it runs)

Am I doomed to use one of the two first solution (IConvertible/explicit cast) ?

Comment: You've given us a lot of `Employee` code, but you seem to query an `Order`. I've quickly tested with your `Employee` (using a `List<Employee>` and stripping the username and password code) and was able to query on `.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Number == 5)` just fine. Please share the code for `Order` as far as I can see the problem is not in this code.

Comment: Thinking about it I retract my statement. Testing with a `List` instead of a `Query` was not really representative, could very well be something within the translation to whatever query language is being generated behind the scenes. Point stays though that you're querying and `Order` but provided no code for that.

Comment: @Knoop Oops you are right, I shared the wrong code. I edited my question. And yes the problem arises in a `Query` where NHibernate is not able to extract an `int` from an `EmployeeNumber` automatically.

Comment: Thanks for adding the `Order` code. Yeah my assumption will be the same, sadly I don't have any knowledge about what exactly is going on there so I can't help you with that. Hope you'll find your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create my own custom types for my different value objects:

```
public sealed class EmployeeNumberUserType : SingleValueObjectType<EmployeeNumber>
{
    protected override NullableType PrimitiveType => NHibernateUtil.Int32;
}

public abstract class SingleValueObjectType<TValueObject> : IUserType where TValueObject : class
{
    public SqlType[] SqlTypes => new[] { PrimitiveType.SqlType };

    public Type ReturnedType => typeof(TValueObject);

    public bool IsMutable => false;

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner) => cached;

    public object DeepCopy(object value) => value;

    public object Disassemble(object value) => value;

    public new bool Equals(object x, object y) => x?.Equals(y) ?? y?.Equals(x) ?? true;

    public int GetHashCode(object x) => x?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;

    public object NullSafeGet(DbDataReader rs, string[] names, ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        var obj = PrimitiveType.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0], session, owner);
        if (obj == null) return null;
        else return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TValueObject), obj);
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(DbCommand cmd, object value, int index, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        if (value == null) cmd.Parameters[index].Value = DBNull.Value;
        else cmd.Parameters[index].Value = value.GetType()
                                                .GetProperty("Value", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                                                .GetValue(value);
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner) => original;

    protected abstract NullableType PrimitiveType { get; }
}
```

And explicitely using this custom type in the mapping:

```
public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        Id(Entity.Expressions<Order>.Id);
        Map(x => x.EmployeeNumber)
            .Unique()
            .CustomType<EmployeeNumberUserType>();
    }
}
```